# How to *optimally* draw multiple images in WebGL (i.e. texture atlas)

Tags: image, webgl, textures, texture-atlas

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321781/drawing-multiple-2d-images-in-webgl) lists how to draw multiple images in WebGL but it draws them one at a time which I've learned is suboptimal.

What was recommended is using texture atlassing or perhaps something else. Somehow reducing the draw calls. Can you demonstrate generally how this works, with some code or pseudocode?

(I am trying to create a photo gallery with many vector-like drawings alongside dozens of photos in a grid, then you select a photo and zoom in.)

Comment: how many things will you be drawing at once? You say photo gallery. When I use things like Windows Explorer, Picasa, iPhoto, etc to show a photo gallery there are only about 100 thumbnails on the screen at any one time. Even if I make the the thumbnails small there are at most 400. There is likely no need to optimize drawing 400 thumbnails

Comment: Good to know, would still be interesting to know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 100s of ways. Which way depends on your needs.

The simplest example though it to just take one of the most common examples of how to draw a cube with 6 images one on each face.

[How to map different textures to different faces of a cube in WebGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116831/how-to-map-different-textures-to-different-faces-of-a-cube-in-webgl)

Now adjust the positions of the faces of the cube so they are separated and all facing the same way. Here is the same example from the answer linked above but with the faces move to all face the same direction

```js
"use strict";
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
// compiles shader, links and looks up locations
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

function quadPoints(x, y) {
  return [
    x - .5, y - .5, 0,
    x + .5, y - .5, 0,
    x + .5, y + .5, 0,
    x - .5, y + .5, 0,
  ];
};

function uvCoords(x, y, width, height, imageWidth, imageHeight) {
  const left   = x / imageWidth;
  const bottom = y / imageHeight;
  const right  = (x + width ) / imageWidth;
  const top    = (y + height) / imageHeight;
  return [
    left, top,
    right, top,
    right, bottom,
    left, bottom,
  ];
}

const textureAtlasDimensions = [512, 256];
const thumbnailDimensions = [128, 128];

const arrays = {
  position: [
    ...quadPoints(-3.0, 0),
    ...quadPoints(-1.8, 0),
    ...quadPoints( -.6, 0),
    ...quadPoints(  .6, 0),
    ...quadPoints( 1.8, 0),
    ...quadPoints( 3.0, 0),
  ],
  texcoord: [
    ...uvCoords(  0,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(128,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(256,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(  0, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(128, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(256, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
  ],
  indices:  [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23,
  ],
};
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

// calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: "https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/noodles.jpg",
  crossOrigin: "",
});

const uniforms = {
  u_texture: tex,
};

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 20);
  const eye = [0, 0, 10];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];

  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(view, projection);
  const world = m4.rotationZ(time * .1);

  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(world, viewProjection);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  // calls gl.uniformXXX, gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  // calls gl.drawArray or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = texcoord;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
}
  </script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

You've just drawn 6 images with 1 draw call.

You can move the images separately by updating the vertex positions and re-uploading them with `gl.bufferData`

```js
"use strict";
var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.getElementById("c").getContext("webgl");
// compiles shader, links and looks up locations
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);

function quadPoints(x, y) {
  return [
    x - .5, y - .5, 0,
    x + .5, y - .5, 0,
    x + .5, y + .5, 0,
    x - .5, y + .5, 0,
  ];
};

function uvCoords(x, y, width, height, imageWidth, imageHeight) {
  const left   = x / imageWidth;
  const bottom = y / imageHeight;
  const right  = (x + width ) / imageWidth;
  const top    = (y + height) / imageHeight;
  return [
    left, top,
    right, top,
    right, bottom,
    left, bottom,
  ];
}

const textureAtlasDimensions = [512, 256];
const thumbnailDimensions = [128, 128];
const baseQuad = quadPoints(0, 0);

const position = new Float32Array([
  ...quadPoints(-3.0, 0),
  ...quadPoints(-1.8, 0),
  ...quadPoints( -.6, 0),
  ...quadPoints(  .6, 0),
  ...quadPoints( 1.8, 0),
  ...quadPoints( 3.0, 0),
]);

const arrays = {
  position,
  texcoord: [
    ...uvCoords(  0,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(128,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(256,   0, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(  0, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(128, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
    ...uvCoords(256, 128, ...thumbnailDimensions, ...textureAtlasDimensions),
  ],
  indices:  [
    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7, 
    8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11, 
    12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15, 
    16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23,
  ],
};
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

// calls gl.createTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.texImage2D, gl.texParameteri
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: "https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/noodles.jpg",
  crossOrigin: "",
});

const uniforms = {
  u_texture: tex,
};

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  const projection = m4.perspective(30 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 20);
  const eye = [0, 0, 10];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];

  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const viewProjection = m4.multiply(view, projection);
  const world = m4.identity();

  uniforms.u_worldViewProjection = m4.multiply(world, viewProjection);
  
  // move the vertices of the quad
  const numQuads = 6;
  for (let i = 0; i < numQuads; ++i) {
    const u = i / (numQuads - 1);
    const x = -3 + u * 6;
    const y = Math.sin(time + u * Math.PI * 2) * 2;
    for (let j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      const srcOffset = j * 3;
      const dstOffset = i * 12 + j * 3;
      position[dstOffset + 0] = baseQuad[srcOffset + 0] + x;
      position[dstOffset + 1] = baseQuad[srcOffset + 1] + y;
    }
  }
  // upload them to the gpu
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.position.buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, position, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  // calls gl.uniformXXX, gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  // calls gl.drawArray or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0px; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
  v_texCoord = texcoord;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
}
  </script>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Now add more quads instead of just 6

Comment: I'm afraid to ask you any more questions, but I still wonder if it might be better if I loaded images in my own data texture rather than creating like a JPG of 1 image. All your answers have been super helpful.